# If User Input Matches Multiple Dictionaries Then Display Value

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, input

A similar question was asked by db-rocker in which he/she looped through a single dictionary to match with user input to display the value the input matched with the key. However, for my application, I'm not sure if using dictionaries at all is the way to go. I'm developing a program that takes a part number (written in xxxx-xxxxxxx-x fashion) and breaks down each section to give back to the user. For example, the part number 7L3Z-14D696-A is a heating element used in 2007 Ford 150 trucks that has been revised once. Trying not to get off track, but essentially the program would go through each part section to determine this information (prefix, main, and suffix). For each part, I have one or more dictionaries that will take the user input to get the right information. So far the prefix I have the following written.

```
    Years = {"A": 2010, "B": 2011, "C": 2012, "D": 2013, "E": 2014, "F": 2015, "G": 2016, "H": 2017,
     "J": 2018, "K": 2019, "L": 2020, "M": 2021, "N": 2022, "P": 2023, "R": 2024,
     "S": 1995, "T": 1996, "V": 1997, "W": 1998, "X": 1999, "Y": 2000,
     1: 2001, 2: 2002, 3: 2003, 4: 2004, 5: 2005, 6: 2006, 7: 2007, 8: 2008, 9: 2009}

    #Product Line Codes
    PL = {

   "S1": "Aspire", "S2": "Contour", "S4": "Escort/Focus", "S5": "Ka", "S6": "Fiesta",
   "S7":"Mondeo", "S8": "Probe", "S9": "Mystique",
   "M1": "Tracer",
   "F1":"Taurus", "F2": "Windstar", "F3":"Continental", "F4":"Sable", "F5": "Villager", 
   "F6":"Thunderbird",
   "F7": "EN158", "F8": "FW178", "L1":"Bronco", "L2":"Explorer", "L3": "F150/F250", "L4": 
   "Maverick 4X4",
   "L5": "Ranger", "L6": "Aerostar",
   "R1": "Aston-Martin", "R2": "Falcon", "R3": "Mustang", "R4": "Scorpio", "R5": "Fairlane", 
   "R6": "LTD",
   "R8": "Jaguar S-Type", "R9": "Mark VIII",
   "W2":    "Cougar",
   "W3": "Grand Marquis",
   "W4":    "DEW98",
   "W5":    "EW171",
   "W6":    "Thunderbird RWD",
   "W7":    "EN114 Crown Vic",
   "W8":    "Jaguar XK8/XKR",
   "W9":    "Jaguar XJ-Series",
   "C1":    "Transit",
   "C2":    "Econoline",
   "C3":    "Medium Truck",
   "C4":    "L-Series/Cargo-CF Series Truck",
   "U1":"Power Products",
   "U2":    "Motorcraft Brand",
   "U3":    "Outside Sales",
   "U4":    "#3"
    }

  R_Code = {

"A": "Light Truck Engineering",
"B": "Body Engineering",
"C": "Chassis Engineering",
"D": "Overseas Product Engineering",
"E": "Engine Engineering, Engine Product and Manufacturing Engineering",
"F": "Electronics Division, Product Engineering Offc" ,
"G": "Electronics Division, Arbor Plant" ,
"H": "Climate Control Division, Product Engineering Offc" ,
"J": "Ford Customer Svc. Division Parts and Accessories Engineering Offc" ,
"K": "Import Component Engineering, Body Engineering" ,
"L": "Ford Customer Svc. Division Power Products/Ford Cust. Svc. Engineering" ,
"M": "Performance Operations, Special Vehicle Operations" ,
"P": "Transmission and Axle Product and Manufacturing Engineering (Automatic Transmissions)" ,
"R": "Transmission and Axle Product and Manufacturing Engineering (Manual Transmissions)",
"S": "Light/Heavy Truck Engineering, Truck Special Order Department" ,
"T": "Heavy Truck Engineering" ,
"U": "Electrical and Fuel Handling Division, Product Energy Office",
"V": "Domestic Special Order Engineering Section, Car Special Order and Special Vehicle Engineering" ,
"W": "Transmission and Axle Product and Manufacturing Engineering (Axle and Driveline)" ,
"X": "Plastic and Trim Products Division" ,
"Y": "Ford Customer Service Division (Lincoln and Mercury), Product Analysis and Publications" ,
"Z": "Ford Customer Service Division (Ford), Product Analysis and Publications" ,
8: "Electric Vehicle Engineering",
5: "Ford PN96/UN98 Platform Engineering"
}
```

This is the prefix only. To get this from the user, I have the following written:

```
    prefix = input("Please enter the prefix number: ")

    if len(prefix) == 3:
       if prefix.isupper() == False:
       prefix = prefix.upper()
    if Years.get(prefix[0]) != None:
    year = Years.get(prefix[0])
    #get Product Line portion of prefix/2 characters
    for char in prefix[1:2]:
        prefix = prefix[char]
    if PL.get(prefix) != None:
        prod_line = PL.get(prefix)
    #now get the last character in prefix for design responsibility
    if char in prefix[3] in R_Code.get(prefix[3]):
        design = R_Code.get(prefix[3])
        print("your vehicle is a", year, " ", prod_line, design)
        
     else: print(prefix, "not found")

 else:
    print("Prefix should be 4 characters only")
```

I apologize for the indention mistakes but I'd really like to know before I proceed with the rest of the program is an honest opinion. Nothing against if statements but if there is a more sufficient way to go about this, then I would really appreciate the advice.

Comment: Clearly, a set of dictionaries is the right way to do this.  PLEASE NOTE, however, that you are working with character strings here, not integers.  You should not have keys like `1`, `2`, and `3`.  You should have quoted strings: `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, etc.

Comment: Also, your `for char` loop is wrong.    The product line is just `prefix[1:3]`, and the R code is just `prefix[3]`.

Comment: @TimRoberts good to know. I was unsure about that as well (strings vs integers) but it does make sense; thank you for your input.